# What is the earliest level 5 hack?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

I know there's at least one level 4 lock in Detroit in the first section of the game. However, I'm wondering how soon I need to max out my hacking skills if I want to be able to hack absolutely everything.

Comment: Perhaps you may want to clarify your question to be the earliest point at which a level 5 hack becomes inaccessible? While [CyberSkull's answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/29532/what-is-the-earliest-level-5-hack/29533#29533) is correct, I don't think it answers the intention of your question, since you can return to places like Sarif HQ and the basketball court much later in the game

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would upgrade to level 5 before leaving Detroit for the first time.

The police station has at least a level 4 hack for the armory, as I recall - it might be level 5 - and you will not be able to get in on your second trip to Detroit. So you need level 4 if you want to do all the hacking you can.

However, once you have level 4, you can upgrade to level 5 to break in to an illegal aug shop in the Brooklyn Court apartment building in Detroit. Inside of that aug shop, you can find a Praxis kit. This is accessible later, but since the upgrade pays for itself and will make your future hacking easier, you may as well get it as soon as you can.

Comment: Where is this illegal aug shop?

Comment: In one of the apartment buildings. The outer door is guarded by a level 5 security panel. Inside, as I recall, there's an operating table and a storage cage.

Comment: In Detroit?....

Comment: Yes, in Detroit.

Comment: It's the Brooklyn Court building, the same one that the neuroprozine quest takes you to.

Comment: @CyberSkull: I have to thank you too, because I didn't have time all day to look it up! I'm going to edit it in.

Comment: Near the edge of the city next to the police station you'll see a tall fence. If you grab a large trash container you can hop over it and get the access code from a body to the illegal aug shop and some extra XP as well. Of course, you'd also get a praxis without having to get level 5.

Answer (score 4):

Sarif HQ has a few level 5 hacks. For instance, the helipad storage room & Pritchard's computer.

Comment: There's also one on the garage next to the basketball court.

Comment: Most of the ones in detroit and even a bit further don't need to be hacked though, you can generally find codes for them.

Comment: @Mr Smooth Hacking gives more XP tho, so I would recommend hacking them, even if you got the code.

Comment: @mordi Yeah I hack everything anyway because of the exp

Comment: There are a few caches in Detroit I skip hacking so I can get the goodies inside faster. For example, the heliport storage has a weapon mod in there.